# React dynamic nested form input

Tags: reactjs, arrays, forms, nested

Im a newbie in React and Im creating a simple form that sends data to DB. I made it work almost as I wanted, the only problem is that I dont know how to update the state which has an array inside.
The idea is to make a form so I can add recipes which include the whole recipe data that I map through to render each recipe. In the data object I need simple strings most of the time but then I need also three arrays or objects, **I prefer the arrays in this case**.

I found many solutions for class components but still I could figure out how to update the arrays. I even figured out how to update one array from a string input separated only with commas, then .split(', ') and .trim() and map() through but I could not setFormFields({}) at two places at the same time since the createRecipe() is async. The split just did not happen before the array was sent to the DB as a string. Thats why I dont put the whole code here.

I will simplify the code to make you see clear.

```
const defaultFormFields = {
      title: '',
      imageUrl: '',
      leadText: '',
    };

const NewRecipeForm = () => {

  const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState(defaultFormFields);
  const { title, imageUrl, leadText } = formFields;
  const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState([])


  const handleFormFieldsChange = (event) => {
    setFormFields({ ...formFields, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
  }
  const handleIngredientsChange = ( event) => {
  **// here I need help**
    setIngredients()
  }

  const addIngredient = () => {
    setIngredients([...ingredients, ''])
  }

  const removeIngredient = (index) => {
  **// here I need help**
}

  const createRecipe = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    // addRecipe sends the object to Firestore DB
    addRecipe('recipes', url, formFields)
    resetFormFields()
  }

  const resetFormFields = () => {
    setFormFields(defaultFormFields);
  };

  return (
    <NewRecipeFormContainer>
      <h1>New recipe</h1>
      <form onSubmit={createRecipe}>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <input label='Title' placeholder='Recipe title' name='title' value={title} onChange={handleChange} />
        <input label='imageUrl' placeholder='imageUrl' name='imageUrl' value={imageUrl} onChange={handleFormFieldsChange} />
        <input label='leadText' placeholder='leadText' name='leadText' value={leadText} onChange={handleFormFieldsChange} />
        <h1>Ingredients</h1>
      **// here I need help ?**
        {
          ingredients.map((ingredient, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                <input label='Ingredience' placeholder='Ingredience' name='ingredient' value={ingredient.ingredient} onChange={handleChange} />
              **// here I need help ?**
                <button onClick={removeIngredient} >remove</button>
              </div>
            )
          })
        }            
        <button onClick={addIngredient} >add</button>
      </form>
      <Button onClick={createRecipe}>ODESLAT</Button>
    </NewRecipeFormContainer>
  )
}
```

I will appreciate any hint or help. Ive been totally stuck for two days. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to update a single element in a list.

```
const updateSingleItemInList = (index, update) => {
  setList(list.map((l, i) => i === index ? update : l));
};

const add = (element) => setList([...list, element]);
```

Try simplifying your state first:

```
const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState([]);
const [tips, setTips] = useState([]);
```

Then it becomes simple to write the handlers:

```
const updateIngredient = (index, text) => {
  setIngredients(list.map((ing, i) => i === index ? text : ing));
};

const addIngredient = () => setIngredients([...ingredients, ""]);
```

Then you can create the form object when the user wants to submit:

```
addRecipe('recipes', url, {
  ingredients: ingredients.map(i => ({ingredients: i})),
  // etc.
});
```

Put it all together and here is the minimum viable example of a component that manages a dynamic number of form elements (tested, works):

```
export const TextBody = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([{ name: "anything" }]);

  const add = () => setList(l => [...l, { name: "" }]);

  const remove = i => setList(l => [...l.slice(0, i), ...l.slice(i + 1)]);

  const update = (i, text) => setList(l => l.map((ll, ii) => (ii === i ? { name: text } : ll)));

  return (
    <>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={add}>
        <Text text="add" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {list.map((l, i) => (
        <>
          <Text text={JSON.stringify(l)} />
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => remove(i)}>
            <Text text="remove" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Input onChange={c => update(i, c.nativeEvent.text)} />
        </>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

You can return those CRUD functions and the state from a custom hook so you only have to write this once in a codebase.

Edit: Just for fun, here's the same component with a reusable hook:

```
const useListOfObjects = (emptyObject = {}, initialState = []) => {
  const [list, setList] = useState(initialState);

  const add = () => setList(l => [...l, emptyObject]);

  const remove = i => setList(l => [...l.slice(0, i), ...l.slice(i + 1)]);

  const update = (i, text, field) =>
    setList(l => l.map((ll, ii) => (ii === i ? { ...ll, [field]: text } : ll)));

  return {
    list,
    add,
    remove,
    update,
  };
};

export const TextBody = () => {
  const { list, add, remove, update } = useListOfObjects({ name: "", id: Math.random() });

  return (
    <>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={add}>
        <TextBlockWithShowMore text="add" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {list.map((l, i) => (
        <React.Fragment key={`${l.id}`}>
          <TextBlockWithShowMore text={JSON.stringify(l)} />
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => remove(i)}>
            <TextBlockWithShowMore text="remove" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Input onChange={c => update(i, c.nativeEvent.text, "name")} />
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for a hint. I still havent been able to fully complete the task. Am I supposed to create 50 handlers just because I have 3 arrays in the state object? handleChange, handleAdd and handleRemove for each of them? Doesnt sound like the right solution. And I dont think the problem is that complex, so why cant I find a working example anywhere? I havent been this stuck for a long time.

Comment: You can write handlers for list of objects on an object...but it's going to be really messy. It's far better if you simplify your state first. I've elaborated in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, windowsill, for trying to help me. I'm still that dumb that I couldn't figure it out. I tried like dozen of variants, but still I couldn't figure out how to update my array of strings/objects and then render all the added inputs (new ingredients). I read the React documentation through, I've been searching for posts about useState onChange handler, I've been watching youtubers etc but no-one is going 'that far', everyone shows just simple examples. I bet it's so simple. I made some changes in the original post. I tried your solution but it wasn't working for me. SOMEBODY PLEASE HELP!:)

Comment: Man, thank you. Now I get it. The problem was missing that anonymous function in onChange. The more you stare at the code, the less you see. Have a good one :)